# pre-loaded module in ocaml, and their contents

Tags: module, ocaml

Two questions:

1. How can I find what are the modules that are pre-loaded in my ocaml session?
2. Given a module, how can I list its contents?

In SML, a standard "trick" was to define a dummy module and open in it a module the contents of which I wanted to inspect. The signature of the dummy module would then list the contents of the module in SML. This does not work in ocaml.

**Found this:** To see the packages pre-loaded, use `#use "topfind";;` to use the topfind package, and the `#list;;` will list the pre-loaded packages!

Comment: For two, that's a tooling problem. You can use either merlin in vim/emacs or you can use ocp-browser. Both available on opam, the ocaml package manager.

Comment: `#list` will not show all preloaded modules, but will show _packages_ that **can be** loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to list the modules currently loaded.

To show the contents of a module:

```
# #show_module Pervasives;;
module Pervasives :
  sig
    external raise : exn -> 'a = "%raise"
    external raise_notrace : exn -> 'a = "%raise_notrace"
    val invalid_arg : string -> 'a
    . . .
    val unsafe_really_input : in_channel -> bytes -> int -> int -> unit
    val do_at_exit : unit -> unit
  end
```

The initial set of top-level directives is given in [Section 9.2](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec256) of the OCaml manual.

Comment: This works from 4.02... I need to upgrade. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the leading `#`. It's part of the directive.